# xargs split incoming line

Tags: xargs

I have a file with two columns separated by spaces like this:

```
potato 5
apple 7
pretzel 9
```

I want to issue a command on each line like this:

```
cmd -f potato -n 5
cmd -f apple -n 7
cmd -f pretzel -n 9
```

Can I get `xargs` to split the incoming line and pass those arguments to a command? Is `xargs` even the right command to use here?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that directly with xargs, but there's another solution :

```
$ cat /tmp/l
potato 5
apple 7
pretzel 9
```

using printf:

```
$ printf 'cmd -f %s -n %s\n' $(</tmp/l)
cmd -f potato -n 5
cmd -f apple -n 7
cmd -f pretzel -n 9
```

if you need to execute it, you can use another pipe to the shell, like

```
$ printf 'cmd -f %s -n %s\n' $(</tmp/l) | bash
```

Another simple & pure awk solution :

```
$ awk '{print "cmd -f "$1" -n "$2}' /tmp/l
cmd -f potato -n 5
cmd -f apple -n 7
cmd -f pretzel -n 9
```

Finally :

```
$ awk '{system("cmd -f "$1" -n "$2)}' /tmp/l
```

Comment: works great and is simple enough that I can hope I'll eventually remember it... my question is, any easy modification to convert this working example `echo 11 22 | awk '{print "echo -f "$1" -n "$2}'` to have a CSV line input instead of space-delimited, like this: `echo 11,22`  ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
cat food.txt | parallel --colsep ' ' cmd -f {1} -n {2}
```

It will also run one `cmd` per cpu core in parallel.

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1